# While loop only looping a small area of the code rather than all of code that is actually in the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a small text game of which a person has to guess the name of the song correctly and with only two guesses, I have created a while loop so that I can use this two guess system; However, it is only looping a small area of the code and not what I want it to loop.

Below is the code being used (Of which includes the while loop)

```py
#song guess entry

ans2 = input("Enter the name of the song: ")

#change all the capitalisation to lowercase
ans2 = ans2.lower()

time.sleep(0.5)

x = 0 

#while loop to allow two attempts at the Question
while x != 2:
    print("LOADING...")
    time.sleep(1)
    #correct or incorrect?
    if ans2 == song:
        if x == 1:
            print("\nYou gained 1 point for guessing it the second time!")
            score = score + 1
        if x == 0:
            print("You gained 3 points for guessing it first time!")
            score = score + 3

        time.sleep(0.5)

    if ans2 != song:
        print("\nIncorrect! No points gained")
        x = x + 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

When executing the program I ensured that the song I entered was actually correct multiple times. When this problem first happened it was displaying nothing after it asked for the user to enter the song name, I then put a print statement after the while loop starts just to try and visualise the problem.

```py
#while loop to allow two attempts at the Question
while x != 2:
    print("LOADING...") # where i added the print statement
    time.sleep(1)
```

The result of executing the code is this:

```
Enter the name of the song: buffalo soldier
LOADING...
LOADING...
LOADING...
LOADING...
LOADING...
LOADING...
LOADING...
LOADING...
LOADING...
```

The 'LOADING...' does not stop.

Comment: I did have x = 0 before the while loop it was just further up the code, I added it in just before the while loop and is now giving a different result. Instead of simply just printing ```LOADING...``` It now is repeating ```You gained 3 points for guessing it first time!
LOADING...
```

Comment: Did you make sure `x=0` is defined just before the while loop? Because I can't see any problem other than this.

Comment: @CameronDugmore Added solution to that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the question within the while:

```
#song guess entry
import time
x,score = 0,0
song = 'buffalo soldier'
#while loop to allow two attempts at the Question
while x != 2:
    print("LOADING...")
    ans2 = input("Enter the name of the song: ")
    # change all the capitalisation to lowercase
    ans2 = ans2.lower()
    time.sleep(1)
    #correct or incorrect?
    if ans2 == song:
        if x == 1:
            print("\nYou gained 1 point for guessing it the second time!")
            score = score + 1
        if x == 0:
            print("You gained 3 points for guessing it first time!")
            score = score + 3
        break
    else:
        print("\nIncorrect! No points gained")
        x = x + 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't re-initiate your `x`, so it is probably over 2 after the first run you made, and it's going 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6... infinity (as `x != 2` is always *True*). You need to assign `x = 0` just **before** the loop. In addition, if it was the wrong answer, you don't ask the user for a new one inside the loop. Add `ans2 = input("Enter the name of the song: ")` to the code if the user was wrong inside the loop.

Comment: Won't it give a `x not defined` error if we don't initialize it first?

Comment: @Sarques Because he did define it somewhere before in the code not shown here, but he then run just this part of the code, and doesn't start `x` from 0 again.

Comment: Yeah sure, that must be the reason here.

Comment: So I will need to add x = 0 at the beginning of the while loop?